# dojo: A gap between dijit.layout.BorderContainer and its child

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I followed the following site to do some layout in dojo:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/dijit_layout/
The problem is there's gap between BorderContainer and its children. How to eliminate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `gutters` attribute to false.

```
new BorderContainer({
    ...
    gutters: false
});
```